# GoogleBot sending weird content-type to API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, googlebot

Several of Google's bots are hitting one of our URLs to our API and they are sending a weird Content-Type header that looks like this:

> "content-type":"application/json; charset=appli"

Node.js JSONParser does not seem to like this (Specifically the charset=appli) and crashes. We handle this crash of course and send an error response but I feel like there should be a better solution to this.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'll also add that this is an API call made by our chrome extension. As soon as we submitted the app to the store we started getting these calls, I assume its some type of automated test of the extension (though it does not have googlebots User-Agent). It also never checked the Robots.txt file on the site.

Comment: How do you make API calls from your extension @ABlankensjp? Extensions itself doesn't set any special headers besides the ones set by default by the browser.

Comment: They weren't running our extension as it didn't follow the expected flow of the app, they just started hitting 1 of our endpoints with POST requests with no data and that header.